# Match nested object in document against array of possible matches

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to match a nested object in a Mongo document against an array of possible matches.

The documents look like this:

```
{
  prop1: ...,
  prop2: ...,
  prop3: {
    p3a: 1,
    p3b: 7,
    p3c: 1051
  }
}
```

I have an array of potential matches for `prop3`:

```
[ { p3a: 1, p3b: 7, p3c: 1051 }, { p3a: x, p3b: y, p3c: z}, ... ]
```

Is there a way to perform this matching? Preferably using the aggregation framework, but even if it's possible to perform it otherwise, that would still work.

- There is no way to change the structure of the model, it has a lot of old code tied to it, so even if it's not optimal, I have to work with it or around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't want aggregation for this since it means forcing a computation to marry up the matches.

What you want instead is to remap your source data from the "unqualified" key names to "fully qualified" key names to use in a query.

For example:

```
 var arr = [ { p3a: 1, p3b: 7, p3c: 1051 }, { p3a: 'x', p3b: 'y', p3c: 'z'} ]
```

Can be transformed:

```
 arr = arr.map(d => 
   Object.keys(d).reduce((o,k) => Object.assign(o, { [`prop3.${k}`]: d[k] }),{}));
```

A bit cleaner with ES6 style JavaScript, but the mongo shell does not support the newer syntax:

```
 arr = arr.map(d =>
   Object.entries(d).reduce((o,[k,v]) => ({ ...o, [`prop3.${k}`]: v }),{}) );
```

Which makes the list now:

```
[
        {
                "prop3.p3a" : 1,
                "prop3.p3b" : 7,
                "prop3.p3c" : 1051
        },
        {
                "prop3.p3a" : "x",
                "prop3.p3b" : "y",
                "prop3.p3c" : "z"
        }
]
```

And now you simply query with [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
db.collection.find({ $or: arr })
```

So that's all you need to do as [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) accepts an array of conditions and the only thing missing from your "list" is that the keys to match are not yet prefixed using ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) for the full path including the `"prop3"`.

There is no such thing as a "preference" for forcing computations when a regular query which can actually even use an index as long as those property paths don't change is going to get the job done effectively and efficiently

Comment: Works like a charm!

My preference for the aggregation framework was because I want to do further operations on the retrieved documents that would be suitable to be handled by it.

I don't understand the part about 'forcing a computation', if you know of a resource that would clarify this point, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @OmarAlqady I think you're a bit confused here. With the aggregation framework you simply put the same query condition in a `$match`. Your question is about a "query" and nothing to do with aggregating, but writing such a statement implies to others you are "expecting" that we need to "calculate" where to match "your list" against a key. What I said here is "you don't", and instead just make the list of conditions be valid for the query.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I thought you were referring to the usage of aggregation in general, but you meant my phrasing of the question. That clarifies things.